# How to init database without main class in WPF application (code-first with Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework

I have a little problem with my database. I want to create the database using Entity Framework (code-first) but all tutorials showing how to do so do it in a console application using something like this in their `main` class method:

```
exampleDb.Example.Add(); 
exampleDb.SaveChanges();
```

But I want to create my database in a WPF application. What should I do?

thanks, mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your App.xaml.cs file, it should be under App.xaml, override OnStartup, then init your database.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{   
    base.OnStartup(e);  

    exampleDb.Example.Add(); 
    exampleDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It works. I used migrations too and finally created my db.